# Unsupported operand type(s) for +

Tags: python, flask

Используется flask, sqlalchemy
Выбираю наибольший id из бд и потом увеличиваю на 1

```
max_id = db.session.query(func.max(User.id)).scalar()
id = max_id + 1
```

В ответ получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

если в консоли python сделать тоже самое, работает нормально
если проверить например

```
max_id = db.session.query(func.max(User.id)).scalar()
type(max_id) == int
true
```

Кстати,на локальном сервере работает, на рабочем, нелокальном не работает
Что не так? Почему не хочет прибавлять?

Answer (score 0):

`db.session.query` возвращает None.
Когда вы пытаетесь прибавить к нему единицу, возникает операция None + int, которая и дропает вам вашу ошибку.

Проверяйте корректность инициализации `session`. Проще говоря, связь с базой данных, существование нужных сущностей и атрибутов и т.д.